# Polars: Read Pandas Data Frame and Include Column Headers

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

Right now, when I use polars to read a pandas dataframe, I lose the name of the field. Is there a way to not lose the field name?

I tried first reading the pandas df in the following way:

```
df = pl.from_pandas(pd.read_excel(excel_path))
```

Then tried reading the excel straight into polars - when I did it this way, the first row is just the column names:

```
df = pl.read_excel(excel_path, 
                      read_csv_options= {"has_header":False, "new_columns": ["DataMonth", "ZipCode", 
                                                                             "Total_Claimed_Subscribers", "Total_Claimed_Devices",
                                                                             "Service_Support", "Device_Support", "Total_Support"]})
```

Comment: No one can answer this without seeing the file. By default the header row becomes the column names so there must be something peculiar about the file you're loading.

Comment: Probably there is some value on the first row, maybe add `skip_rows = 1`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your responses on this! It's actually related to how Jupyter Notebooks in Vscode handles dataframes. Over the weekend I used df.head(N) and saw the column names

Here's more on polars and jupyter

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12519